# Convolutional Neural Networks - resolution

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to ask you a question regarding CNNs. Is it possible to train CNNs for such kind of pictures (~ 1100 x 703 pixels). They are scatter plots, which can be classsified into 2 categories (signal and background) based on the patterns of the dots. However, as far as I know images in the CNN process are shrinked into 256 x 256 pixels. Do you think the CNN will be able to resolve patterns in such scatter plots?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that CNNs can only use 256 x 256 images as inputs?

Comment: Classifying MNIST images is the “hello world” of convolutional neural networks, and those images are $28\times28$, so $256\times256$ is not a requirement of CNNs. I am with @Sycorax in wondering what got you thinking that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Maybe I asked the question in wrong way.
I am following this video (https://youtu.be/jztwpsIzEGc?t=2353), where guy is building CNN model and applying it to any images. There is defined image_size = 256x256. It means that I shoudl change it in my case of scatter plots or not?

Comment: What size are your images?

Comment: 1595 x 842 pixels